# Using an if statement to detect words that begin and end with the same letter

Tags: java, string, if-statement, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a program using scanner which takes input from the user and determines whether the input begins and ends with the same character.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class L7E6{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String word;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type a word: ");
        word = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (word.charAt(0).equals(word.length()-1)){
            System.out.println("The word "+word+" begins and ends with the character "+word.charAt(0));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The word "+word+" begins with "+word.charAt(0)+" and ends with "+    (word.length()-1)+" these characters are not the same.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have used `charAt(0)` and `.length()-1` to determine first and last characters previously, but it doesn't seem to be working here.

Comment: `word.length()-1` does not return the last character, it returns the length of the word minus 1. As should be evident from your 'wrong' output line -- it prints the *length* instead, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do `if (word.charAt(0).equals(word.charAt(word.length()-1))){...}`. In your code you compare the first character with number.

Answer (score 0):

You could even do this since you're comparing `chars`

```
if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length()-1)) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.charAt(0)==str.charAt(str.length()-1)){
            System.out.println("equal");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has suggested this yet:

```
if ( word.endsWith(String.valueOf(word.charAt(0))) )
{
    System.out.println("Success!");
}
```

This won't handle null Strings, but does handle empty strings.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than mucking around with letter indexes, you could use regex:

```
if (word.matches("(.).*\\1|.") {
```

The first part of the regex uses a back-reference to the captured first letter to assert that the first and last letters are the same.
The "|." (meaning "or a single character") is to handle the edge case of a single letter word.

Answer (score -1):

if (word.charAt(0)==(word.charAt(word.length()-1)))
This will work. 
equals() is used only for checking the equality of strings.

Comment: The left hand side is a character, while the right hand side is an integer?

Comment: Did you mean `if (word.charAt(0)==word.charAt((word.length()-1)))`?